# MongoDB Number Field will not insert or update with the number that I input

Tags: mongodb, insert, insert-update, mongodb-query

this is my problem:

> db.Group6391102Bounds.insert({ bound:"latest",id:138548488276343678,complete:false})
>   db.Group6391102Bounds.find()

```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297d9e5ef9f659b82271617"), "bound" : "earliest", "id" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297dc28b2d702ea878b540d"), "bound" : "latest", "id" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
```

> db.Group6391102Bounds.insert({ bound:"middle",id:138548488276343678,complete:false})
>   db.Group6391102Bounds.find()

```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297d9e5ef9f659b82271617"), "bound" : "earliest", "id" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297dc28b2d702ea878b540d"), "bound" : "latest", "id" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297dc3cb2d702ea878b540e"), "bound" : "middle", "id" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
```

> db.Group6391102Bounds.insert({ bound:"middle",name:138548488276343678,complete:false})
>   db.Group6391102Bounds.find()

```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297d9e5ef9f659b82271617"), "bound" : "earliest", "id" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297dc28b2d702ea878b540d"), "bound" : "latest", "id" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297dc3cb2d702ea878b540e"), "bound" : "middle", "id" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5297dc91b2d702ea878b540f"), "bound" : "middle", "name" : 138548488276343680, "complete" : false }
```

As you can see, even though I insert a specific ID, mongoDB will add a different ID.
I have no Idea why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Happy Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I did not understand your question in the beginning and therefore provided wrong answer (thanks cababunga for pointing this out). So here is a correct one.

Mongoshell supports different [data types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#data-types-in-the-mongo-shell). And it tries to guess your datatype when you enter it. So you enter your big number: **138548488276343678**. Note that it is bigger then then 2^31-1 which is the maximum for 32-bit integer. So it treats it as a float and because floats are not stored precisely, it modifies it a little bit. This is why your stored number is almost the same, but differs by a little bit (this difference will be less then 8). But you want to store this number precise and mongo support 64-bit integer (which fits your integer).

So you need to specify that you want to store it as [64bit integer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong). You can do this in the following way:

```
db.a.insert({
  bound:"latest",
  id: NumberLong("138548488276343678"),  // Note these "". I was not using them and the number was not stored correctly
  complete:false
})
```

After this you can retrieve your document `db.a.find()` and it will be correct. Note that a lot of drivers have similar problems and therefore you have to explicitly tell that you are going to save them as 64bit integer.

> And here is my wrong attempt. If you thing that it should not be here,
>   please modify my question:

If you are not specifying `_id` for the document you are creating, mongodb creates `_id` field by itselft. You can read a little bit more about `_id` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19972202/1090562) and in [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

If you have your own field, which you would like to be used as `_id`, instead of writing `id:138548488276343678` you should write `_id : 138548488276343678`.

P.S. also because I see that you are using quite big numbers, keep in mind that integers in mongodb as stored as [64-bit integers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) (which means that it is between -2^63 to 2^63 - 1)

Comment: `_id` has to be unique. As you can see in the sample, `id` is same in each insert.