# Updating int array gets converted to double array in Mongo shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have int array to update in collection using mongo shell  .When I update  it  actually it stores in double format .

```
var  array =[1,2,3];     // int array as all elements are int 
                         // Update query where path is the collection field
 db.doc.update({},{$set : {“path”:array}},{ upsert: true });
```

Actually it stored:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("529ae0e70971d81eedf5cb3d"),
  "path" : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
}
```

I am novice to mongo and have to run update query in mongo shell. How to avoid auto double conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mongoshell treats numbers as float by default. So if you want them to be treated as something else, tell this to mongo explicitly. For your case, you have to use [NumberInt()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberint).

So `var array = [NumberInt("1"), NumberInt("2"), NumberInt("3")];`

P.S. you might find my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276675/1090562) (which is similar) helpful as well.