# How to save document with "id", not "_id" in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Like in the Title is there any way to save my document in database where id would be "id", not "_id" ? I write server in Node.js with mongoose.

Comment: You can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971670/how-can-i-change-id-field-in-mongodb-collection-to-user-id)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i change \_id field in MongoDB Collection to User\_id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971670/how-can-i-change-id-field-in-mongodb-collection-to-user-id)